# How to make a table of descriptive statistics in R

Tags: r, database

This is the data I have now, and it is a dataset with students from different education levels(F1) and several variables about their academic performance[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd2ls.png)
And I want to use R to make a table of descriptive statistics like this one
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzfTw.png), which has the mean and standard deviation of each variable group by their education level.

```
aggregate(. ~ F1, dt3, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

I have used this function, but the result is not identical to the one I want.

Here is a mini sample of my data.

```r
structure(list(F1 = c("Elementary school", "High_school", "High_school", "Elementary school", "Junior_high_school", "High_school", "Kindergarten", "Kindergarten"), X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), X3 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), X4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), X5 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4), X6 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4), X7 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4), X8 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4), Y1 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4), Y2 = c(4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 14L, 696L, 15L, 1348L, 1364L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add input data and  result in text format.

Comment: I suggest checking out the `papaja` package: https://rpubs.com/YaRrr/papaja_guide

Comment: @NingyaoXu, I edited my answer to provide you the code that should work with your small example. Please add the example directly in your question, it will make things easier for people trying to follow your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NingyaoXu, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your dataset.

Based on the capture image of your dataset and your example (I replace `F1` by `education` in your example), I would suggest that you use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. You can try:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(., -education, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  group_by(education, Variable) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Value), Sd = sd(Value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(., names_from = "education", values_from = c(Mean, Sd))%>%
  select(., Variable, contains("Elementary school"), contains("High_school",ignore.case = F), contains("Junior_high_school",ignore.case = F),contains("Kindergarten"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, here is a mini reproducible example of my dataset.

Comment: structure(list(F1 = c("Elementary school", "High_school", "High_school", 
"Elementary school", "Junior_high_school", "High_school", "Kindergarten", 
"Kindergarten"), X1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), X3 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), X4 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), X5 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4), X6 = c(4, 
4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4), X7 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4), X8 = c(4, 
4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4), Y1 = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4), Y2 = c(4, 
3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 14L, 696L, 15L, 
1348L, 1364L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you add this example to your question instead ? It will be easier for people to see it than digging in comments ;)